# Android duplicates fragments when screen rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my current app I am using two fragments. They are positioned like this:

in portrait view

```
|F1|
|--|
|F2|
```

and in landscape view:

```
|F2|F1|
```

Where:
F1 is a map fragment
F2 is a list fragment

The layouts have this same name and are placed in two folders: `layout` and `layout-land`.

I am setting up my fragments in activity `onCreate()` method:

```
private void displayFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case MAIN_FRAGMNET:
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String
                    .valueOf(position));
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new MainListFragment();
            }
            break;
        case MAP_FRAGMENT:
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String
                    .valueOf(position));
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new EMapFragment();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            if (fragment instanceof EMapFragment) {
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapContainer, fragment);
            } else {
                setSelection(position);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.listContainer, fragment);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

and in `onCreate()`

```
    displayFragment(MAP_FRAGMENT);
    displayFragment(MAIN_FRAGMNET);
```

According to documentation on rotation activity lifecycle is recreated. So everything should be done as it would be opened as a new app. However, it isn't.

Each time when I rotate the device the fragments are duplicated - options in `ActionBar` menu are duplicated and the second list is trying to load - this is only showing the initial layout message, but loader isn't started for a second time.

The first (initial) list is still visible.

Can someone please advice what am I doing here wrong? I want fragments always to be single, so when rotated truly everything is rebuild.

Comment: can you post the code for your fragments?

Comment: *so when rotated truly everything is rebuild.* - then call that display method only when the savedInstance is null(the activity is not being recreated) and properly position the fragment containers in the two layouts.

Comment: @Luksprog please put it as an answer, because it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the `displayFragment()` method in the `onCreate()` callback, only when the passed in `Bundle` is null meaning that the `Activity` is not being recreated(if the `Activity` is recreated then the fragments will be made available by the system). Then in your two layouts just change the position of the two fragments containers to match the desired design. The system, having those two layouts available, will take care of properly recreating the two fragments along with placing them in the containers.